# SQL - Multiple Relationships Between Two Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, relationship

I have a Users table and a Tasks table.

In the Tasks table, I'd like to have columns for Created By and Modified By.

Both of these columns should have foreign keys to the Users table.

Is this as simple as creating a foreign key from each column to the Users table or is there a recommended approach I should be taking here?

Comment: It is as simple as creating two foreign key relationships.

Comment: Normally one tried this and if it fails you ask a question ! :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick and straight-forward answer @GordonLinoff. Now, isn't this some sort of data integrity issue? Circular reference of some type? I haven't seen any documentation explaining this. If there's somewhere I can look to educate myself here, please let me know.

Comment: @LuisVidal . . . I really have no idea what you are asking.  Users has a primary key.  Other tables can contain references to users through the primary key.  Such tables can have more than one reference, and you have a good example of that.

Comment: lol You're absolutely right Riggs, but experience has also shown me that trial and error can sometimes lead to hours of overcomplicating something simple or, worse, taking incorrect shortcuts and perpetuating bad code... I really just want to learn "the right way" from the start so I appreciate the help! =/

Comment: I've never really seen a database schema that had more than one relationship between tables... Maybe it's because I'm new to building databases, but just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something in the grand scheme of things...

Comment: @LuisVidal, a many-to-many relationship is common and certainly involves a junction table that has at least 2 relationships. Example: Customers, Products, Sales (or Purchases). Sales (or Purchases) would have relationship with both Customers and Products. A table that has multiple relationships to another table is also not uncommon - example in question is a valid for instance. And tables can have relationship that involves a self-join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing strange about this at all. (With respect, you may be overthinking it.)

Your Task entity has two Users (created and modified). The columns for each of those can be configured as its own foreign key from your Task to your User table.  No problem.

But my experience tells me you should consider a different way of handling this problem of associating User and Task.  I suggest you add a third table called, maybe, Action.

It will have a row for each action a User takes with respect to a Task.  It might look something like this.

```
action_id  task_id  user_id action  ts                    description
   214        48      97    create  2020-01-29T12:33:00   
   215        48      34    edit    2020-01-29T14:25:00   explain how to test
   216        48      88    edit    2020-01-29T14:48:00   update explanation
```

`action_id` is an autoincrementing pk.  `task_id` is FK to the Tasks table, and `user_id` is FK to the Users table.  The purpose of this Actions table is to track what users did to tasks.  And it's straightforward to query the first action, or the last action, taken on the  Task.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! This is exactly what I meant. Totally understand a table connecting to multiple tables. No problem. But two tables should not have more than one relationship between them. Your solution here is the more "appropriate" way of handling this issue. Better to overthink things when starting a project than trying to change things later when you've got all sorts of dependencies to account for. Thanks again!